# Efficient sorting when you only want the best

Tags: c#, sorting

I have a `list` of 5000 items that are sorted using a custom algoritm.
I only need the best one, i.e. `list[0]` after the sort has completed.

So I need an algoritm that takes the first item of the list, compares it to the second item and then compares the better one of these two, with the third item etc. Just one loop through the whole list (order n).

Which sorting method in c# should I use for this rather common scenario?
I believe the `Sort(..)` algoritm that I currently use is very inefficient for this purpose.

Comment: It's Easy algorithm, You can write it on your own. It's about 5/6 lines of code.

Comment: Why do you need to sort at all? Can't you just keep a reference to the best as you traverse the list?

Comment: If "best" has the same meaning as "biggest" or "smallest" value, you can simply use `Enumerable.Max` or `Enumerable.Min`.

Comment: @PaoloTedesco,@MajkeloDev Yes I can, only I imagined that there would be a simple existing method for such a common requirement.

Comment: @Daniel Hilgarth Of course the custom sort is not a simple Max/Min.

Comment: In any case, I don't see why this question should be downvoted without any comment - for one, I ignored the existence of Enumerable.Max, so +1 from me :)

Comment: Which `Sort`-algorith ARE you currently using? There is one that has a delegate as parameter where you can specify how to do so. Add some code in order to evaluate which is more appripriate to you.

Comment: Why do you have to sort? Only 1 loop and take the best one.

Comment: @Gerard Obviously. Max / Min aren't helping when the sorting is working on a sub value of the value you want to have as a result. However, have a look at my changed answer. It uses MaxBy. It will work, no matter what your sort algorithm might be.

Comment: If this is an effeciency-question, which it seems to be to me, you should consider using a performance-profiler for best approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the [`MaxBy`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32946516/138078) of MoreLinq with selection, projection, source and key somewhat too complicated and just used my own code as an extension method:

```
    public static T GetBest<T>(this List<T> list, IComparer<T> comparer)
    {
        if (list == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("list");
        if (comparer == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("comparer");
        if (list.Count > 0)
        {
            T best = list[0];
            for (int i = 1; i < list.Count; i++)
            {
                if (comparer.Compare(best, list[i]) > 0)
                {
                    best = list[i];
                }
            }
            return best;
        }
        return default(T);
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`MoreLINQ's MaxBy()`](https://code.google.com/p/morelinq/source/browse/MoreLinq/MaxBy.cs) for this.
Depending on how you define "best", the selector parameter you specify might be different.

Example: You have a list of strings and the "best value" is the longest string.

```
string longestString = listOfStrings.MaxBy(x => x.Length);
```

As you can see from the linked implementation, this is `O(n)`. This is the best that is possible for an unsorted set.